# Objective-c: ccTouchesBegin End and Moved not Firing when using Custom Sprites

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a Ship Class, in this Ship Class i have the methods ccTouchesBegin, ccTouchesEnd and ccTouchesMoved. But these methods never fire:

Here is the Ship Class:

```
//
    //  Ship.m
    //  Asteroids
    //
    //  Created by trikam patel on 06/08/2014.
    //  Copyright 2014 trikam patel. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "Ship.h"
    #import "Helper.h"

    @implementation Ship


    // on "init" you need to initialize your instance
    -(id)init:(NSString*)imageName :(NSMutableArray*)asteroids
    {
        if( (self=[super init:imageName]) ) {

        asteroids = asteroids;

        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {
        for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];

        if(allowedToMove){
            if(hasShipHit){
            if(!shiphit){
                shiphit = [[CCSprite alloc] init];
                CCSpriteBatchNode *spritesheet = [Helper setupAnimation:@"shiphit" :2 :shiphit];
                [self addChild:spritesheet];
            }

            [shiphit setPosition:ccp([self position].x, [self position].y)];
            [shiphit setPosition:ccp(point.x, point.y + 76)];
            }else{
            [self setPosition:ccp(point.x, point.y + 76)];

            }

        }


        }
    }


    -(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];

        NSLog(@"begin move ship");
        if(hasShipHit){
            int shipX = [shiphit position].x;
            int shipY = [shiphit position].y;
            if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake (shipX - 20.5, shipY - 96, 50, 50), point))
            {
            allowedToMove = true;
            }
        }else{
            int shipX = [self position].x;
            int shipY = [self position].y;

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake (shipX - 20.5, shipY - 96, 50, 50), point))
            {
            allowedToMove = true;
            }
        }

        }

    }

    -(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
        for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];
        allowedToMove = false;
        }
    }
```

This is how the Ship Class gets used in the Parent:

```
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    Background *backgorund = [[Background alloc] init:@"bg1.png"];
    [self addChild:backgorund];

        ship = [[Ship alloc] init:@"ship.png" :asteroidArray];
    [ship setPosition:ccp(100, 100)];
    [self addChild:ship];
```

Comment: in your Ship class, did you enable touch processing ?

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, i added touch processing in the parent layer inside init

Comment: not certain how that would work to be honest (at least in cocos2d v3, never used it).  You need the callbacks in the object which is touch enabled ... which implies that your business logic could be quite different if you detect from the parent (container of ships), vs the ship itself.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, should i do all the collision detecting and keeping track of the Ship, Bullets and Asteroids in the Parent layer rather than in the Ship Class?. Im just trying to keep up with the Apple Code Standard Specification.

Comment: Read, learn, try things, but do your own thing ... eventually you will have your own patterns and standards, which imo can only be better than some bit of apple dogma. As for a specific answer here, i'd need to understand your app much better to offer guidance (and not in this forum :) ) ... but : if touch related events tend to involve multiple 'touchables' and 'types of touchables', their relationships and what they are allowed to do, i would do it outside of the 'touchable' class per say. Each would need too much context which is not typically their concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ship class must enable touch processing so it respond to Touch methods such as TouchesBegan and TouchesEnded. If I got it correct, your Ship class is a custom CCSprite or something similar, so probably it won't have any isTouchEnabled property.

Use your touches methods in your Parent Layer and call your ship methods from there.

Something like...

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for(UITouch *t in touches){
        CGPoint point = [self convertTouchToNodeSpace:t];
        [ship methodForTouch:point];
    }
}
```

Hope it helps :)